# Printing out each element of list of tuples several times

Tags: haskell

Given a list of tuples like this `[('a',2), ('b', 6), ('c', 1)]` I'm trying to print out the char each time in a string.

I'm looking for an output like this `"aabbbbbbc"` in a string on one  line.

I'm trying to do this using `replicate`, for example `replicate (snd x) (fst x)` but this didn't work.

Comment: Can you please show the exact attempt you made?

Comment: What do you mean that your attempt "didn't work"? Did you get a specific error message? Did you get a result other than what you expected? Can you explain?

Answer (score 6):

If you have a list of items, you can use [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) to construct a list where the given function is applied to all elements of the given list. We thus here can make use of `replicate`, like:

```
map (\x -> replicate (snd x) (fst x))
```

to obtain a list of items, where for an item `('a', 2)`, we are thus given `"aa"`. For the sample data, we thus obtain:

```
Prelude> map (\x -> replicate (snd x) (fst x)) [('a',2), ('b', 6), ('c', 1)]
["aa","bbbbbb","c"]
```

This is of course a list of list of elements. We can use [**`concat :: Foldable f => f [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat) to concatenate the elements together, or use [**`concatMap :: Foldable f => (a -> [b]) -> f a -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) to combine `map` and `concat`:

```
Prelude> concatMap (\x -> replicate (snd x) (fst x)) [('a',2), ('b', 6), ('c', 1)]
"aabbbbbbc"
```

We can use pattern matching here to avoid using `fst` and `snd`:

```
concatMap (\(x, y) -> replicate y x)
```

or we can make use of [**`uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) and [**`flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) and write the function as:

```
concatMap (uncurry (flip replicate))
```

Answer (score 6):

This could be done using [list comprehensions](http://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension) (where `xs` is your list of tuples):

```
concat [replicate n x | (x, n) <- xs]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by just making the definition

```
foo [('a',2), ('b', 6), ('c', 1)] = "aabbbbbbc"
```

Is this a correct definition? Yes.

Is there some problem with it? Yes, it is not general enough. It will only accept a very very specific and narrow form of input, and error out on everything else:

```
> foo [('a',2), ('b', 6), ('c', 1)]
"aabbbbbbc"
it :: [Char]

> foo [('a',2), ('b', 6), ('c', 2)]
"*** Exception: <interactive>:13:5-51: Non-exhaustive patterns in function foo
```

Anything else wrong with that definition? Well, not wrong per se, but it's lacking a *type signature*. GHCi can infer the type for us:

```
> :t foo
foo :: (Num t, Eq t) => [(Char, t)] -> [Char]
```

but it seems too general for comfort. We can specialize is e.g. as

```
foo ::                [(Char, Int)] -> [Char]
```

So, with this type, what can be done about the definition? Starting from the missing case, we add

```
foo [('a',2), ('b', 6), ('c', 2)] = "aabbbbbbcc"
foo [('a',2), ('b', 6), ('c', 3)] = "aabbbbbbccc"
```

All correct cases. But what about making them more general?

For that, we try re-writing it and trying to see some patterns in it:

```
foo [('a',2), ('b', 6), ('c', 4)] = "aabbbbbbcccc"
                   = "aabbbbbb" ++ "cccc"
                   = "aabbbbbb" ++ replicate _ 'c'
```

What is the value to go into that `_` slot?

When you've answered that, you'll be able to also complete this one:

```
foo [('a',2), ('b', 6), ('c', n)] = "aabbbbbbcccc"
                   = "aabbbbbb" ++ "cccc"
                   = "aabbbbbb" ++ replicate _ 'c'
```

and this one:

```
foo [('a',2), ('b', m), ('c', n)] = "aabbbbbbcccc"
                   = "aabbbbbb" ++ "cccc"
                   = "aa" ++ replicate _ _ ++ replicate _ 'c'
```

and isn't this the same as

```
foo ( ('a',2) : [('b', m), ('c', n)] ) = 
                   = replicate _ 'a' ++ foo [('b', m), ('c', n)]
```

or even

```
foo ( h : t )  
    | h == ('a',2)
    , t == [('b', m), ('c', n)] ) 
                   = replicate _ (fst h) ++ foo t
```

… right?

Could you continue this line of thought to its conclusion? Do you see how the code practically *writes itself* when we *generalize* our concrete cases by replacing concrete terms with variables?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a folding job.

```
Prelude> foldr (\(c,n) r -> replicate n c ++ r) "" [('a',2), ('b', 6), ('c', 1)]
"aabbbbbbc"
```

I use `foldr` to make concatenations to the head of the accumulator `r` which is more efficient.

Or as for a monadic approach you may write like

```
Prelude> let decode = (uncurry (flip replicate) =<<)
Prelude> decode [('a',2), ('b', 6), ('c', 1)]
Prelude> "aabbbbbbc"
```